# Adding rows to table with self-referencing foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

I've created a table called TableTest with two columns `ent` and `dep`. `ent` is the primary key and `dep` is the foreign key which references `ent`. I create the table using:

```
CREATE TABLE TableTest (
  ent varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  dep varchar(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (ent),
  FOREIGN KEY (dep) REFERENCES TableTest(ent)
);
```

I must show that the three values (A1,A2,A3) depend on one another. A3 is dependent of A1 etc. However when I try to insert a row into my table such as:

```
INSERT INTO TableTest(ent, dep)
  VALUES ('A1','A3');
```

I get the following error and after doing research I'm still stuck on how to get by this. I'm very new to SQL.

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases, just like the one you posted, where circular references (which are absolutely fine by the way, no logical issue there) conflict with the normal way relational integrity constraints work. This is because relational integrity has some "directional" features (primary key comes first, then foreign key) even though dependencies can be circular, as you have seen.

There are several work-arounds. The easiest is to make the foreign key constraint `deferred`. That means that the constraint is checked only when you `commit`, not after each individual `insert`.

Another is to insert all values at the same time (in the same `INSERT` statement); for example:

```
insert into tabletest(ent, dep)
  select 'A1', 'A3' from dual union all
  select 'A3', 'A2' from dual union all
  select 'A2', 'A1' from dual
;
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to insert the `root value`.

```
> insert into TableTest values ('A1', null);
> insert into TableTest values ('A3', 'A1');
```

Comment: would this not be stating A3 as the ent and A1 as the dependent in this case? A3 is dependent of A1 so should they not be switched. When I do that though I still get a similar error.

Comment: There is no "root value" - the OP never said the data is a tree. And indeed it is not; it is a cycle. The OP said the dependencies are circular. I see your answer already has three up-votes; even so, if I were you I would delete it, since you clearly did not understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Pablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54373648/3208640) is okay but you can do something alse too if you don't want to have `null`s; First insert same value for both `PK` and `FK` and then insert the relation:

```
insert into TableTest values ('A1', 'A1');
insert into TableTest values ('A3', 'A1');
```

Comment: And then DELETE ('A1','A1')? That is not part of the OP's data, so it should not be left in the table.

Comment: @mathguy you won't be able to delete that row, since the second one depends on it.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz - that is not what I meant. I believe I understood the OP's problem correctly (unlike you and Null); I may be right, considering that the OP marked my answer as "correct". Namely, the task is to enter three rows into the table, with values (A1, A3), (A3, A2) and (A2, A1). (Why you both wanted to insert (A3, A1) is unclear to me.) So, suppose we start with (A1, A1) as a crutch, then we add (A2, A1) and (A3, A2). Finally, one would now have to update the (A1, A1) row, changing it to (A1, A3) - which will work. But (A1, A1) should not remain there, and it doesn't have to.